# PHP POST with swagger

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using PHP 7.0 and in my code I will receive form post parameter and once I will get parameter than I will run my logic than redirect to some website.

Now my question is can I use swagger in this kind of project, if yes than kindly can you guide me.

Sorry for bad question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swagger is meant for building, designing, ..., APIs. It sounds like you just want to handle form data, so I don't think swagger isn't really made for those kind of purposes. You'd be better of with building a regular backend controller.

For more information, i'd recommend taking a look on their [website](https://swagger.io/) under the "Why Swagger?" menu and decide by yourself whether it's useful for your project